# what features of ImageMagick give photo effects like iChat "video effects"

Tags: python, imagemagick

[image: Here is an example]I have a python ride sharing google app which places pins on a map so that group members attending an event or a workplace can identify car pooling opportunities. I would like to add a snapshot feature to the pin but want to also make it possible to edit the snapshot sort of like "video effects" does in iChat, so that folks are more likely to be willing to put up a non-identifying snapshot of themselves.

Is there an existing app or library for photo effects (no video is involved) that could be added to my app? Or is there a generic name for the type of library I am seeking.

Actually, while entering tags I noticed ImageMagick. It looks like ImageMagick is a great candidate for my needs. What features of ImageMagick can I look for?

Comment: adding an example of the effect will help users who don't know what iChat effects are to get an idea of what you want to acheive

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ImageMagick is probably the funniest way to go. IM is highly portable across operating systems, and many programing languages offer libraries to work with IM's API. For Python, you have a choice of three libraries:

- [PythonMagickWand](http://www.assembla.com/wiki/show/pythonmagickwand)
- [PythonMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/download/python/)
- [Wand](http://dahlia.github.com/wand/)

ImageMagick also supports [FX expressions](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/fx.php); which, you can use to build-out elaborate effects (like the ones you see in iChat). Effects can be dynamically created, or you can create templated mask to apply to user photos.

Here's some examples of mask-generation, and composite effects, by using IM's command-line interface.

```bash
# Create circle mask
convert -size 200x200 xc:white \
        -draw 'circle 100,100 60,60' \
        -blur 0x10 \
         circle.jpg
# Apply effect
composite circle.jpg me.jpg -displace 15x15 me_circle.jpg
```

[image: circle] [image: me_circle]

```bash
# Create mask with text
convert -size 200x200 \
        -font Helvetica -pointsize 52 \
        -background white \
        -fill black label:'Stack\nOverflow' \
        -distort Arc 360 \
         font.jpg
# Apply effect 
composite font.jpg me.jpg -displace 15x15 me_font.jpg
```

[image: font] [image: me_font]

Comment: IM is new to me. Your 2 examples each show 2 panels. Is the left panel an input or an output; I assume the right panel is an output. I especially don't understand the second example because I don't see a text file anywhere. In the first example creation step is `circle.jpg` an already provided input file, or is it the file being created? This all looks very promising, but I will need some time to digest IM and evaluate the results.

Comment: For each example: The left panel is the output image generated by the first `convert` command. The second `composite` command applies the previous generated left panel with an additional image, **me.jpg**, and outputs the displaced results as the right panel image. [Additional examples](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/mapping/#displace_areas)

Comment: Ok, I think this will work, but it looks like it could be a lot of study and work for me to implement. I have found a couple of free Mac-specific apps that will work on newer Macs and iOS devices that take either existing photos or photos via a computer cam and can produce pretty neat photo effects to obfuscate a photo. I would like to learn of similar apps for windows, android, and linux os's so that while I wait for user feedback on this feature, I can suggest existing apps for use. Any ideas, folks? Thanks.